# kpartx device to image mapping

Tags: mount, loop-device, kpartx

I am using kpartx to map the paritions of an image file to device mapper. kpartx maps the image to one of the free loop devices, for example, /dev/loop0

Is there a way to query what image is mapped to which device?

for example a command that takes in /dev/loop0 for instance and return the path for the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is available with `/sbin/losetup -a`.

Comment: dmsetup info seems to have no information regarding the backing image

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding the q. first.

Comment: no problem. Do you know if the information in losetup -a can be retrieved from the proc fs? or any other file?